# What does Employee Alignment mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> You want to improve employee alignment, engagement and effectiveness as you grow your business.

I know it means:

> arrangement in a straight line, or in correct or appropriate relative positions.
>   a position of agreement or alliance.

but here I don't get its meaning about employee.

Comment: Think about **in correct or appropriate relative positions**.  If you have a team rowing a boat, you would like them all rowing in the same direction. You would like them to be aligned so that the boat moves in the direction you would like it to go, as well as being arranged relative to each other so that they aren't bumping into each other as they row. It would help to have more context. Where did you find this sentence? What are some of the sentences surrounding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Employee alignment" is what might be termed "management speak". The sentence means that you want (or need) to ensure that your employees have the same stated goals (of improving the business). Someone who is not aligned does not have the same goals: he may be working for you solely to improve his resume and is not dedicated to the success of the company. Another possibility is that someone thinks that the company should be in market y whereas you (or the owner or manager) have decided that the company should be in market x.